# No node_modules from netlify deploy

Tags: npm-install, netlify

I've got continuous deployment setup with Netlify and a git repo but so far no matter what I do, Netlify isn't `npm-install`ing anything. There's no node_modules folder when I download a zip of the deploy, my site can't access node_modules, it's just not there. I've started with a random npm package (lodash) to try to get it to install but I've got nothing so far.

Netlify says that it automatically runs `npm install`. I've tried having no build commands and I've tried adding `npm install` as a build command with no results from either.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "netlify-test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "stuff",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/electrovir/netlify-test.git"
  },
  "author": "electrovir",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/electrovir/netlify-test/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/electrovir/netlify-test#readme",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.11"
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>
        hi
    </title>
    <script src="node_modules/lodash/_apply.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Why can't this find node_modules??
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It took a while to figure this out but I discovered that Netlify *does* `npm install` into your repo root or **Base directory** when you have a `package.json`. This can be seen by changing the **Build command** to something like `ls` and reading the deploy console output (there will be a `node_modules` folder listed).

However, at some point after running the **Build command** and before deploying, this `node_modules` is deleted. Hence, if you use something similar to the following as a **Build command**, `node_modules` can be copied to your **Publish directory**:

```
rm -rf dist && mkdir dist && rsync -rv * dist --exclude ./dist
```

This copies the **Base directory** contents into `dist`, which I have set as my **Publish directory**, ignoring `./dist` itself (it can't be copied into itself). It'd be even better if this were added as an npm script in `package.json` with `npm run <script name>` for your **Build command**.

Note that **Base directory**, **Build command**, and **Publish directory** are all under *Deploys > Deploy settings* or *Settings > Build & deploy* in Netlify.

Thanks to [lastmjs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2196424) for help with figuring this out.

Comment: I am very very happy to have found your answer, and very very disappointed at Netlify for needing it.

Comment: Vercel recently started deleting node_modules in my builds too, breaking my deployments. https://github.com/vercel/vercel/issues/10791 (in case anyone was thinking of switching)

Answer (score 3):

It would be odd if `node_modules` WERE there.  Netlify's continuous deployment does run npm install for you, if and only if there is a package.json in the root of your repository (or instead in the `base` directory if you set one in [netlify.toml](https://www.netlify.com/docs/netlify-toml-reference/).  However, it also uses a custom npm directory that is outside of the deployment directory (see how it is setup here:  https://github.com/netlify/build-image/blob/master/run-build-functions.sh#L34), since deploying your `node_modules` shouldn't be needed for a [static site](https://jamstack.org/) at browse time - only at build time.

The intended path for a Netlify deploy is:

1. you have your dependency manager configuration checked into your git repo at the root of the repo (if no `base` directory is set in the UI or in the toml file) or in the `base` directory if set.  This could be any/all of `Gemfile.lock`, `package.json`, `yarn.lock`, or `requirements.txt` as explained in [this article about the build settings at Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/docs/build-settings/)
2. you do not store your `node_modules` in the repo.  Many of those will be specific to the architecture of the build environment - and your local machine is almost certainly different than Netlify's.  You'll want those generated at build time.
3. your build is intended to USE those modules DURING BUILD.  So you use for instance [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) to read your `.env` file while building, or you use [gulp-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cli) to process your `Gulpfile.js`
4. your build completes, and you've used all the modules during build to generate standalone html/js/css/images, so you're done with them - your static html and other assets are generated in your publish directory, where the build process has intentionally **not** put your node modules, and thus they are not deployed.  Your static website should not need the modules at runtime, so deploying the (thousands!) of files in there is not efficient or needed.

You could have a situation that requires some/one of them - e.g. a [function](https://www.netlify.com/docs/functions/) or you could need a file from one of them even on your static site - and that's fine, feel free to copy it into the publish directory explicitly.  But that is not the norm :)

Comment: I do indeed have `node_modules` ignored in my repo but I don't really have a build process (...yet) but I want my front end to have access to `node_modules`. I'm sorry, I guess I could've been more clear on the build part, but I finally found a solution (which ended up being similar your last paragraph about explicitly copying it all). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This is highly annoying of both Netlify and Vercel in a day and age when we have vanila ES Module web apps that can import anything installed in node_modules (with the most widely used package manager) using import maps.