# My production website don't fint the url node_modules bootstrap and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, sass, node-modules, bootstrap-5

Hope you can help me

I made a simple demo site for my portfolio with bootstrap and jQuery, and I installed it via npm node_modules to work with Sass and change variables default of Bootstrap.

When I've uploaded my project to GitHub through GitHub desktop, it imports ok, but when I deploy the site through netlify, the site doesn't find the URL for my js bootstrap and jQuery. I left below my import script-src code at the end tag body of my page.

```
<!--Script de Bootstrap-->
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<!--Custom Scripts-->
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

I've already has change the path from ../ to / or without slash.

This is the link to my site on netlify: https://thirsty-ritchie-81b315.netlify.app/# Hope someone could help me, because I've searched around a don't fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: This is possible the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/54545546/9406763