# font awesome icons not loading on netlify when using npm

Tags: html, css, node.js, npm, netlify

I am deploying my personal website on netlify and I'm using the following link tag for the icons

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css">`

I tried setting up environment variables for node.js on Netlify and forcing `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` but it didn't solve my problem.

I read in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527465/no-node-modules-from-netlify-deploy#) that Netlify runs `npm install` and then deletes the node_modules folder so the above link tag doesn't work and my page doesn't show the icons.

One of the answers in that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527465/no-node-modules-from-netlify-deploy#) said that **it's wrong to have the node_modules folder on the deployed folder, and that I have to take my resources during build time**. The problem is, I don't know how to do that.

So, I wanted to know if there's a simple workaround besides the one on the [post mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54527465/no-node-modules-from-netlify-deploy#) to keep the node_modules folder in the netlify deployed folder or a little guidance to **get my icons in build time** so I don't need the whole node_modules folder.

Every help is appreciated!

---

Extra information:

[This is the site (with an old deploy that shows the icons)](https://davidchoi.com.ar)

This is how my package.json file look:

```
{
  "name": "david-choi",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "David's Choi personal website",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/choidavid4/david-choi.git"
  },
  "author": "David Choi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/choidavid4/david-choi/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/choidavid4/david-choi.git",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4"
  }
}
```